# Refresh Product Tabs When Child Selected

Tags: configurable-product, tabs

I have a Configurable Product that has Child (Simple) Products.

Some simple products have additional tabs that I've added manually in my theme catalog_product_view.xml
In these custom tabs, sometimes they are empty and sometimes they are populated depending on the product attributes. By default on a simple product page, the tab is not shown if it is empty which is correct.

When it comes to configurable products, the tab doesn't show when a simple product is selected as the tabs are loaded on page load of the configurable, where the tab should be and is empty.

How can I refresh the tabs area when a child product is selected? Essentially, reload the product.info.main section when a child is selected from a configurable dropdown and the tab will show if it isn't empty?

Thanks.